# Triple X-axis at the bottom of the figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, figure, axes

Is there a way to create triple X-axis at the bottom of the figure in Matlab? The Y-axis is the same.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675497/multiple-x-axis-and-y-axis-with-plots-in-matlab) answer help your problem, keeping the `limits` of `y axis` the same? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks Guto. I have a version of such two X-axis, one at the top and one at the bottom. I want to make a plot with all three or more than three X axes at the bottom.

Comment: How do you intend to make it? [Subplots](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) or one over another?

Comment: You can manipulate this : [*How to insert two X axis in a Matlab a plot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009357/how-to-insert-two-x-axis-in-a-matlab-a-plot) to obtain three axis

Comment: @Guto: Not subplot. Just line up 3 axes at the bottom of one figure

Comment: @SardarUsama This is what I want to have. Let me try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Orangeblue, then indeed, the way to go is the one that *Sadar Usama* mentioned. Good coding.